# Why is Gmail not asking for IMAP info when importing mail as I am not receiving emails?

Tags: gmail, imap

[image: screenshot]

It feels like Gmail (mail.google.com) only cares about smtp and email sending but it is not actually fetching new emails. In the configuration popup, it just asks for:

- name
- smtp server
- username
- password

Comment: Where? In what program? How'd you configure the account? This question lacks a lot of information. Please use the EDIT button and improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that feature *is* specifically about sending mail. It doesn't import anything, that's a separate feature 3 lines higher up on the page – look for an "Import mail and contacts" link. (Also, the import feature is POP3 only, it doesn't do IMAP.)